# Velocity.js display: 'block' doesn't work when combined with left: '-50px'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, velocity

Any ideas why when I add `{left: '-50px'},` to the velocity command that the `display: 'block'` and `opacity: 1` aren't applied.

In the CSS `.popover` is set to `display: none` and `opacity: 0`

The whole thing works fine if I remove the display property out of velocity and use .show() from jQuery, but I want to try do it all in velocity.

```
('.popover').velocity({left: '-50px'}, {"opacity": 1}, {display: 'block'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using it wrong, the first object passed to velocity needs to contain the properties to be animated, with the second you are passing options:

```
$('.popover').velocity({
     left: '-50px',
     opacity: 1,
     display: 'block'
}, {duration: 1000});
```

According to the [documentation](http://julian.com/research/velocity/):

```
$element.velocity({ 
width: "500px",
property2: value2
}, {
/* Velocity's default options */
duration: 400,
easing: "swing",
queue: "",
begin: undefined,
progress: undefined,
complete: undefined,
display: undefined,
visibility: undefined,
loop: false,
delay: false,
mobileHA: true
});
```

Comment: Ah I see, I've just started using velocity.js so still trying to understand how it does things.